# How to transcribe bandwidth call recordings in java

Tags: java, bandwidth, transcription, call-recording

My application uses https://app.bandwidth.com/ for receiving incoming calls. I have an api to handle the incoming calls which record the calls when the call is not answered(This recording is treated as a voice mail).

```
if (eventType.equalsIgnoreCase(EventType.ANSWER.toString())) {
   Timestamp callStartTime = new Timestamp(TimeUtil.now().getTime());
   incomingCall.setCallTime(callStartTime);
   callStatus = transferCall(callId, incomingCall.getVoiceForwardNumber(), 1);
}
else if (eventType.equalsIgnoreCase(EventType.TIMEOUT.toString())) {
   voiceMailIntro(callId);
}
else if (eventType.equalsIgnoreCase(EventType.SPEAK.toString()) && PLAYBACK_STOP.equalsIgnoreCase(callState)) {
    recordVoiceMail(callId);
}
else if (eventType.equalsIgnoreCase(EventType.RECORDING.toString()) && 
  state.equalsIgnoreCase(BandwidthCallStatus.COMPLETE.toString())) {
    createTranscription(recordingId);
}
else if (eventType.equalsIgnoreCase(EventType.TRANSCRIPTION.toString()) && status.equalsIgnoreCase(BandwidthCallStatus.COMPLETED.toString())) {
    incomingCall.setVoiceMail(text);
}
```

This is the code for recording call

```
private void recordVoiceMail(String callId) {
   BandwidthClient client = BandwidthClient.getInstance();
   client.setCredentials(bandwidthUserId, bandwidthApiToken, bandwidthApiSecret);
   try {
      Call call = Call.get(client, callId);
       call.recordingOn();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     log.error("An exception occurred while recording voice mail : " + 
     e.getMessage(), e);
   }
}
```

Now i need to transcribe these vocie mails.
From documentation i got methods in python, js, c#, ruby etc. to transcribe the recordings using the recordings.
For example in js,

```
client.Recording.createTranscription(recordingId, function(err, transcription){});
```

I searched every where, but i couldn't find any method in java for that.
Can any one help me if you know ?

Comment: First of all, why haven't you ask your provider? I mean, Why you haven't ask bandwidth.com about that? As I see, that is prepaid service, they should help you

Comment: And could you please show the link to that API of JS?

Comment: @Dred http://dev.bandwidth.com/ap-docs/methods/transcriptions/postTranscriptions.html

Comment: @Dred I asked in bandwidth support. But i didn't get a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, as I see, you need that [link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.bandwidth.sdk/bandwidth-java-sdk/1.14) for java doc.

And [here](https://dev.bandwidth.com/clientLib/java.html?q=) you can follow to java sdk located on Github.

And, also, you can find some more information about transcriptions API [here](https://dev.bandwidth.com/ap-docs/methods/restApi.html?q=Transcription) which you are looking for.

First of all, why do you need that? Perhaps, you do not need that.

As I find, you can't do transcribe with POJO, but you can do something like that.

If you want to do that, you can make it with

```
public void transcribeOn() throws Exception {
    final List<Recording> list = Recording.list(0, 5);

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        final Recording recording = Recording.get(list.get(0).getId());
        System.out.println("\nRecording by Id");
        System.out.println(recording);

        final String recordingUri = mockClient.getUserResourceUri(BandwidthConstants.RECORDINGS_URI_PATH);
        client.post(recordingUri + "/" + list.get(0).getId() + "/transcriptions", null);
        final JSONObject jsonObject = call.toJSONObject(client.get(recordingUri, null));
        call.updateProperties(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure it works correctly, but I hope it put you on correct way